# Ransack causing issues with other queries on the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I'm trying to implement Ransack gem.  I think I have the gem working, but my issue is with other queries on the same model.  For example, I have a simple `<%= @roasts.count %>` on the total number of roasts on my index page. But I get the error `undefined method 'count' for nil:NilClass` when I submit the search query (`http://localhost:3000/roasts?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bname_cont%5D=firefox&commit=Search`).  I'm 90% sure it's due to how I've got the queries set up under the `if-else` statement, but I can't work out the correct setup.

**controller/roast_controller.rb**

```
class RoastsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_roast, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_search

  def index
    if params[:q]
      @q = Roast.ransack(params[:q])
      @roastsalpha = @q.result.order(:name)
    else
      @roasts = Roast.all
    end
      @roastsalpha = Roast.order(:name)
      @roastsdesc = Roast.all.order("created_at DESC")
      @mostpopularroast = Roast.group(:country).select(:country).order("count(*) desc").first
      @mostpopularblend = Roast.group(:bestfor).select(:bestfor).order("count(*) DESC").first
      @countroastschart = Roast.order("roaster DESC").all
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your Index action:

```
def index
    if params[:q]
      @q = Roast.ransack(params[:q])
      @roastsalpha = @q.result.order(:name)
    else
      @roasts = Roast.all
    end
```

You are receiving your error because @roasts is nil. If I am correct in my assumptions that your `set_search` action is doing something like `@search = Roast.ransack(params[:q])` then this is being called before every action and setting `params[:q]`. So if we look at your if statement; `params[:q]` will always be true and @roasts will never be set. I think that to resolve this, you should remove the if-else statement.